# React HTML Table filter onKeyUp error WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

Basically trying to set up a filter to search by a code on a table. With how it is now it just doesn't work. No console error or anything.

I tried changing to onKeyUp={myFunction()} which causes a

> TypeError: (0 , *components_search_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4*_.myFunction) is not a function

error. Been stuck on this for awhile. Appreciate any help.

index.js

```
import NavBar from '../components/navbar.js';
import BSSDTable from '../components/bssd.js';
import React from 'react';
import { myFunction } from '../components/search.js'

export default function Recommend() {
    return (
    <>
        {/* TODO: Color Pallet */}
        <NavBar />
        <div className="flex justify-between text-center pt-5 pb-5">

        <input type="text" id="myInput" onKeyUp={myFunction} placeholder="Enter Class Code" 
        className="input input-bordered w-full max-w-[10rem]" />

        <select className="select w-full max-w-[10rem]">
            <option>Select degree...</option>
            <option>BSSD</option>
            <option>BSCS</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <BSSDTable />
    </>
    )
}
```

search.js

```
export default function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
      if (td) {
        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

bssd.js

```
    <div className="overflow-x-auto">
        <table id="myTable"className="table w-full text-center">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Class Code</th>
                <th>Class Name</th>
                <th>Difficulty</th>
                <th>Recommend</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>C455</th>
                <td>English Composition 1</td>
                <td id="e">Easy</td>
                <td id="soph">Sophia</td>
            </tr>

           </tbody>
         </table>
        </div>
```

Dependencies if it matters

```
  "dependencies": {
    "daisyui": "^2.31.0",
    "next": "12.3.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-daisyui": "^2.4.2",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "typed.js": "^2.0.12"
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a dummy and had the import for the function wrong,

```
import myFunction from '../components/search.js'
```

within index.js fixed the issue.